# Python Heap Priority Queue sift_up()

Tags: python, queue, heap, priority-queue

I am still rather new to Python, but am having a problem with a heap priority queue. Here are my **init**(), **str**(), add(), and my sift_up() method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.queue = []

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.queue)

def add(self, item):
    self.queue.append(item)
    self.sift_up(len(self.queue) - 1)

def sift_up(self, item):
    parent = (item - 1) // 2
    if parent >= 0 and self.queue[parent] > self.queue[item]:
        self.queue[parent], self.queue[item] = self.queue[item], self.queue[parent]
        self.sift_up(parent)
```

Now when I add items to the queue they go in fine. Say, I put this into terminal:

```
pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.add(1)
pq.add(2)
pq.add(45)
pq.add(4)
pq.add(41)
pq.add(5)

pq.__str__()
```

What I get back is '[1,2,5,4,41,45]'. So it looks to sift_up() only somewhat, it doesn't completely reorder the heap.

EDIT: It seems to get screwed up whenever I add a '1' to the queue. In this example I had it return after each add:

```
>>> pq.add(5)
[5]
>>> pq.add(53)
[5, 53]
>>> pq.add(531)
[5, 53, 531]
>>> pq.add(5131)
[5, 53, 531, 5131]
>>> pq.add(1)
[1, 5, 531, 5131, 53]
>>>
```

So it takes whatever element is at [1] and puts it to the back of the queue. I am sure this is trivial, but being new to Python, I can't seem to figure out why.
Again, any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The heap requirement is much looser than you might think. All that matters is that `pq[n] <= pq[2*n+1] and pq[n] <= pq[2*n+2]` for all `n` where the child elements exist. That can allow for a wildly "imbalanced" heap while still maintaining the heap invariant.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help man. I must be thinking about it wrong, if it is supposed to work like that, then I guess I am good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example data, `[5, 53, 531, 5131]`, the computation as you have expressed it in `sift_up` will go like this:

```
# Append 1 to the end
--> [5, 53, 531, 5131, 1]

# The index for '1' is 4, so 'item' is 4.
# (4-1) // 2 = 1 (and 1 >= 0), so 'parent' is 1.
# The value at 'parent' is 53. 53 > 1 is true.
# So swap the value 53 with the value at the end of the list.
--> [5, 1, 531, 5131, 53]

# Now repeat, 'item' starts out at 1.
# The index at (1 - 1) // 2 = 0 (And 0 >=0) so 'parent' is 0.
# The value at index 0 is 5. 5 > 1 is true.
# So swap the value 5 with the value at 'item' (1) to get
--> [1, 5, 531, 5131, 53]
```

So this result follows logically from the way you've coded `sift_up`.

The standard library's `heapq.heapify` function also produces the same thing: it looks like this is the correct behavior for a priority queue:

```
In [18]: import heapq

In [19]: x = [5, 53, 531, 5131, 1]

In [20]: heapq.heapify(x)

In [21]: x
Out[21]: [1, 5, 531, 5131, 53]
```